# Создать переменную в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я через SELECT и CASE создаю условие. Внутри условия мне нужна переменная, которая будет счетчиком (i+1). Как в PostgreSQL можно создать такую переменную?

Пример кода

```
SELECT 

CAST(CASE 
WHEN a = b 
THEN i
ELSE i+1
END AS bit) as id 

FROM mytable
```

Я не могу найти решение, как создать i

Comment: А что вы в целом пытаетесь сделать? Пока похоже, что вы пытаетесь реализовать уже очень давно существующие оконные функции (`window functions`). Такое бывает, если ранее пользовались только mysql до 8.0, где оконных функций не было никаких и приходилось извращаться.

Comment: Можно оформить как анонимную функцию и налепить там любых переменных... Но лучше опишите свою цель, может всё проще, чем вы думаете.

Comment: У меня есть данные о такси (их id), время и их статусах (свободен/занят). Мне нужно разбить строки на поездки, дать индивидуальной поездке свой id. Например, в течение 5 строк машина была на стоянке — этой поездке мы дает id = 1, потом машина поехала — мы даём id=2

Answer (score 1):

В postgresql нет переменных. Они заменяются [оконными функциями](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/tutorial-window). Правда в вашем запросе не понял зачем сумму i+1 приводить к типу данных bit, оно же тогда не сможет быть больше 1 (точнее true).
в общем как то так:

```
SELECT a, b, sum(i) over(order by x) as id
  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, CASE WHEN a = b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as i
      FROM mytable
  ) x
```

В предложении over обязательно должен быть указан порядок сортировки, тот порядок в котором собственно должно периодически расти поле id.

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение! Увы, у меня изначально нигде не задано i, поэтому выдает ошибку «type "i" does not exist»

Comment: @Else "type "i" does not exist", говорит что такого типа не существует. В приведенном мной запросе ни о каких типах речи не идет. И обратите внимание он полностью рабочий https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6zjzKgEMGAD9XXrARdnET3/0 Вы скорее всего зачем то написали там cast, как в вашем изначальном варианте, который используется для приведения типов. Зачем бы в таком запросе приводить типы ума не приложу

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало